# What do you call shortcuts in written English?

Tags: terminology

Writers make shortcuts in their writing and typography such as this sentence:

> He watched my daughter being killed.

Some writers or most of them extract the word *being* out of sentence as a style of writing to be like:

> He watched my daughter killed.

So what do you call these shortcuts in English grammar, and how could I recognize them?

Comment: @StoneyB but i amnot talking about "ellipsis" (...), but my question is why writer remove some words from the context such as "being", and what are they called when you remove the. Are they also shortcuts or has another grammatical meaning?

Comment: @StevanSlewa See this: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ellipsis_(linguistics)

Comment: Am I the only one that sees a postpositive adjective instead of the ellipsis, in the second sentence?

Comment: Some dialects do use a construction like "the car needs washed": see https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/5407/central-pennsylvanian-english-speakers-what-are-the-limitations-on-the-needs-w.

Comment: *He watched my daughter killed* is not grammatical: *watch* requires an infinitive or participial form of *BE* for passives. Do you mean *He **saw** my daughter killed*?

Comment: @StoneyB yes, I do. Is there any difference between saw and watch? As I know both of than are grammatically identical. Because both of them are followed by gerund or infinitive, so what is the difference and why you changed  watch to see?

Comment: *See* and *watch* take different sorts of complement. *Watch* requires  *BE* with the passive, *see* does not.

Comment: @StoneyB SEE, WATCH, HEAR, LISTEN, FEEL, SMELL, NOTICE, OBSERVE + object + bare infinitive http://www.grammaring.com/see-watch-hear-listen-feel-smell-notice-observe-object-bare-infinitive  In this website tells me they are followed by the same thing. Good you please give me an example to show me the difference?

Comment: The passives on that site are passives in the main clause, not the subordinate clause.

Comment: I watched my daughter be killed, or I watched my daughter been killed. Are they now acceptable? @StoneyB

Comment: No - *I watched my daughter be killed* is ok, (but this is pretty rare, because *watch* usually involves an activity with duration), but you want *I watched my daughter **being** killed* for the other